# store gridfs files information in a custom table

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, gridfs

I am using `mongodb` along with a java spring platform as my storage system to store files and documents. As mongo has a limit of `15MB`(Bson storage limit) to store files I have used `GridFs` extension to store my large files. I have implemented this part as follow:

```
DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
        metaData.put("uplad_dateTime", largeDocument.getUploadDateTime());
        metaData.put("title", largeDocument.getName());
        ObjectId id =gridFsTemplate.store(largeDocument.getData(), largeDocument.getName(), largeDocument.getContentType(), metaData);
            largeDocument.setId(id.toString());
```

The problem is that Gridfs by default uses two `fs.chunck` and `fs.files` collections, But I need to store files information with unique file id in a custom document model described here:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection = "document")
public class Document {
@Id
private String id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "document_size", nullable = false)
private long size;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "document_name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "content_type", nullable = false)
private String contentType;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "content_data", nullable = false)
private InputStream data;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "upload_date_time", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime uploadDateTime;

@Column(name = "download_counter", nullable = false)
private long downloadCounter;


public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}


public static final class Builder {
    private Document document;

    private Builder() {
        document = new Document();
        document.setUploadDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public Builder id(String id) {
        document.setId(id);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder size(long size) {
        document.setSize(size);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder name(String name) {
        document.setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder contentType(String contentType) {
        document.setContentType(contentType);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder data(InputStream data) {
        document.setData(data);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder uploadDateTime(LocalDateTime uploadDateTime) {
        document.setUploadDateTime(uploadDateTime);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder downloadCounter(long downloadCounter) {
        document.setDownloadCounter(downloadCounter);
        return this;
    }

    public Document build() {
        return document;
    }
}
```

}

How can I change Gridfs to store file information in my model instead of `fs.files`? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, gridfs provides a facility to associate arbitrary metadata with the uploaded files. This should serve most use cases.

If you require an application object associated with uploaded files, it must be stored in a separate collection.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about that. I just wanted to know what is the best practice to do that.